# Функция скользящей средней для временного ряда

Tags: python, pandas, инспекция-кода, matplotlib, временные-ряды

Для решения этой задачи читал [статью](https://habr.com/ru/companies/ods/articles/327242/)
, посвященную временным рядам. Для нахождения аномалий в первую очередь выбрал функцию скользящей средней, изложенной в этой статье.

Часть датасета:
Time, dB
0,-117
0.0001,46
0.0002,-478
0.000300001,2
..............
59.9998,-208
59.9999,-95
60,-169
Сперва прочитал файл

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep=',')  
df.columns = ['Time, seconds', 'Series values, dB']
```

[image: параметры]

Написал функцию для отрисовки графика, исходя с данных датасета:

```
def plotMovingAverage(series, n):  
    rolling_mean = series.rolling(window=n).mean()  

    plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))  
    plt.title("Moving average\n window size = {}".format(n))  
    plt.plot(rolling_mean, "g", label="Rolling mean trend")  
    plt.plot(series[n:], label="Actual values")  
    plt.legend(loc="upper left")  
    plt.grid(True)
```

И потом вызвал эту функцию:

```
plotMovingAverage(df, 60) #60 секунд 
plt.show()
```

Получился такой график
[image: график]

**ПРОБЛЕМА:**
Но данный график выражает зависимость значение-колво строк(600000), а мне нужен график время-значение. Так же не получается выделить на рисунке саму скользящую среднюю. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как можно это сделать?
Как вообще в данном случае правильно будет написать эту функцию?

Comment: А вы на своем графике видите вашу скользящую среднюю? Я, например, не вижу. Так о какой "правильности" речь идет? Кроме того, вы же нам показываете рисунок, на котором наложено двукратный вывод данных. Что в таких условиях вы от нас хотите услышать?  Что так делать неправильно?  А вопрос - "правильно-ли написана функция НА ОСНОВЕ МОИХ ПАРАМЕТРОВ" -  выглядит вообще как-то мягко говоря странно. Вопрос-то в чем? Проверить ваше домашнее задание перед сдачей его учителю?  Тем более, что функция содержит аж одну строчку вычислительного кода и несколько стандартных функций Matplotlib ?

Comment: @passant Да, вы правильно говорите, я только сегодня понял что все не так: 1) скользящей средней нет. 2) нужно было построить график зависимости время-значение, а у меня вместо времени колво строк стоит(600000). Но я к сожалению пока не знаю как исправить 2 эти проблемы. Буду благодарен если поможете. А вопрос отредактирую

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этом можно сделать еще и другим способом. Для скользящего среднего нам нужно взять определенный размер окна. Здесь мы взяли размер окна = 3600, т.е. скользящее среднее значение 1 час.

```
df['1hour_rolling_avg'] = df['Series values, dB'].rolling(60*60).mean()
```

строим график

```
plt.figure( figsize = (12, 10))   
  
sns.lineplot(x='Time, seconds', y='Series values, dB', data=df)  
sns.lineplot( x = 'Time, seconds',   
             y = '1hour_rolling_avg',   
             data = df,   
             label = 'Rollingavg')  
plt.title('Full Series')  
plt.xlabel('Seconds')  
plt.ylabel('Values')  
  
plt.show()
```

[image: moving average]

Но для лучшего внешнего вида графика, лучше сделать аггрегацию данных, ибо данных много.

Answer (score 1):

Не смотря на обсуждение в комментариях, я так и не понял, что именно вы хотите и что не устраивает в ваших результатах. Поэтому публикую свой вариант решения, где и данные есть, и скользящее видно, и двойного наложения графика нет. Естественно, это пример - на искусственных данных и без вызова функции. Но надеюсь, это не помешает вам подогнать код под свои нужды. (Кстати, никакого поиска аномалий ни у вас в функции ни в моем коде, естественно, нет. Но тут уже не график рисовать надо, а соответвтующие алгоритмы применять. Кстати, можно и без всякого графика обойтись.).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
sr=pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000))
n=100
############################################
rolling_mean = sr.rolling(window=n).mean()  
plt.plot(sr[n:], label="Actual values",color='blue') 
plt.plot(rolling_mean, color="red", lw=3, label="Rolling mean trend")
plt.legend(loc="upper left")
```

Результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Оно?

Comment: Спасибо. Я вот тоже исправил ситуацию, ответил на свой вопрос после вас, вроде похоже на правду. А как без графика можно обойтись а детектировании аномалий?)

Comment: Тут, кстати, может быть достаточно взять пару-тройку стандартных отклонении и посмотреть, какие значения выпадают за диапазон [скользящее среднее - 2 стандартных отклонения : скользящее среднее + 2 стандартных отклонения] - вот и детекция аномалий уже )